# Help with poll in left menu

Tags: magento-1.8, menu, development

I have an problem with the poll in the left menu.
http://caseshop.dk/apple I have disabled the poll feature in system --> Configuration --> Advanced

So then why is it still showing and what can I do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Magento Admin Panel navigate to **CMS->Polls**.Select the poll and set the status to **Closed** .Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx a lot :) I have tried to find out why, but well that poll was removed from the menu when it was disabled. That worked...

Comment: Have a look at this link https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/665-disabling-magento-modules .The post explains why in some cases disabling module from backend won't work.